# Hibernate criteria. Извлечь строку, для которой в связующей таблице есть обе эти записи

Tags: java, hibernate-criteria

Есть 2 обьекта. Room и User. Связь много ко многим.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"Room\"")
public class Room {
private int id;
private List<User> subscribers;

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties("roomList")
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "roomList")
public List<User> getSubscribers() {
    return subscribers;
}

public void setSubscribers(List<User> subscribers) {
    this.subscribers = subscribers;
}

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "\"User\"")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class User implements Serializable{
private UUID id;
private List<Room> roomList;

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@Type(type="pg-uuid")
//@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public UUID getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(UUID id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "\"UserRoomSet\"",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "userid"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "roomid"))
@JsonIgnoreProperties("subscribers")
public List<Room> getRoomList() {
    return roomList;
}

public void setRoomList(List<Room> roomList) {
    this.roomList = roomList;
}
}
```

Мне нужно по входящим двум юзерам найти комнату, в которой они оба есть..

Мой вариант очевидно не правильный:

```
Criteria crt = session.createCriteria(Room.class);
    crt.createAlias("subscribers", "s");
    crt.add(Restrictions.eq("s.id", id1));
    crt.add(Restrictions.eq("s.id", id2));
    List list = crt.list();
```

Подскажите кто в курсе, как это можно реализовать на Hibernate criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Написал этот запрос на нative sql. Может кому-то будет нужно.

```
String sql = " SELECT distinct urs.roomid \n" +
            " FROM public.\"UserRoomSet\" as urs inner join public.\"Room\" r on urs.roomid = r.id \n" +
            " where urs.userid ='"+myId+"'\n" +
            " and r.isprivate = true\n" +
            " and urs.roomid in ( SELECT distinct urs.roomid \n" +
            " FROM public.\"UserRoomSet\" as urs inner join public.\"Room\" r on urs.roomid = r.id \n" +
            " where urs.userid ='"+participantId+"'\n" +
            " and r.isprivate = true);";
```

Теперь осталось это переписать на вариант с критериями.